# Stop UILongPressGestureRecognizer when finger leaves view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

How can I stop, or even detect, when the touch that triggered a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` leaves the view that the gesture is tied too? This behaviour can be seen on `UIButton`s, when the finger leaves the button, the touch event will stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect the leaving and entering with a simple snippet as following:

```
 @objc   func handleLongPress(_ recognizer:UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {


switch recognizer.state {
 case .changed:
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        if view.bounds.contains(recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view) ) {
              print("inside view")
        }
        else {
            print("out of view")
        }
    }
  default:
    break;
  }
  }
```